# How can I get the source files for Arduino libraries?

Tags: library, core-libraries

I've been looking for a while inside Arduino's files to find the core library. However, I haven't found them yet. **Where on my hard drive can I obtain the core library files (.cpp and .h) necessary for all Arduino code?**

Looking around on Google, I couldn't find a way to find the above files. I did see something about getting an .a file while Arduino is compiling, however, that isn't what I want. I want to browse the code and look at functions such as delay to see how they would react when given the values not expected. (i.e. Will my code stall if I use `delay(-200);` by not being to exit the loop, or will it create a black hole and disrupt the space-time continuum?)

Comment: I was interested in the question, but what I want is the source code for *strcpy* and *strcat* in assembler source code. I downloaded the Master Library but I cannot locate anything remotely similar to strcpy or strcat.
OR
Maybe I cannot see the wood for the trees?

Comment: @bobzic I suggest that you ask another question specifying which files you want to find.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The base Arduino source files are in the Arduino installation, under [`cores/arduino/`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino). Source for additional libraries included are in [`libraries/`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/tree/master/libraries).

Comment: And don't forget `/usr/lib/avr/include/` or whatever that translates to on non-Linux systems.

Comment: Too bad I installed it as Windows 10 app and cannot access the installation folder.

Comment: This information seems outdated. The [libraries](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/libraries) folder is empty now and [hardware has moved](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware)

Answer (score 13):

The code is also available online for those times you don't have the IDE installed:

https://github.com/arduino/Arduino

Comment: Can't find the header files there.

Comment: see my answer below: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/68658/59512

Answer (score 9):

On a Mac, the path to the source code folder is:
`Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/Hardware/Arduino/Cores/Arduino`. I'd expect it would be the same from `/Java/` on down in other OSes.

[image: Path to library sources (Arduino-Mac)]

Answer (score 4):

The arduino source files can be found on Github at https://github.com/arduino/Arduino, however the libraries [have been moved](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware#cores-have-been-moved) to their own repositories:

- https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr
- https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-sam
- https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-samd

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple places where you can look. As at IDE 1.6.4 (Ubuntu version) some are in:

```
(install location)/libraries
```

But these are the high-level libraries, in particular:

```
Bridge
Esplora
Ethernet
Firmata
GSM
LiquidCrystal
Robot_Control
RobotIRremote
Robot_Motor
SD
Servo
SpacebrewYun
Stepper
Temboo
TFT
WiFi
```

---

That does not cover the low-level libraries like Tone, Print, main, etc. These are in:

```
(install location)/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino
```

There you would find the Arduino core libraries like:

```
abi.cpp
Arduino.h
binary.h
CDC.cpp
Client.h
HardwareSerial0.cpp
HardwareSerial1.cpp
HardwareSerial2.cpp
HardwareSerial3.cpp
HardwareSerial.cpp
HardwareSerial.h
HardwareSerial_private.h
HID.cpp
hooks.c
IPAddress.cpp
IPAddress.h
main.cpp
new.cpp
new.h
Printable.h
Print.cpp
Print.h
Server.h
Stream.cpp
Stream.h
Tone.cpp
Udp.h
USBAPI.h
USBCore.cpp
USBCore.h
USBDesc.h
WCharacter.h
WInterrupts.c
wiring_analog.c
wiring.c
wiring_digital.c
wiring_private.h
wiring_pulse.c
wiring_shift.c
WMath.cpp
WString.cpp
WString.h
```

---

However even that does not locate things like strcpy. The **header** files for them can be found at:

```
(install location)/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/
```

There you will find:

```
alloca.h
assert.h
ctype.h
errno.h
inttypes.h
math.h
setjmp.h
stdfix-avrlibc.h
stdint.h
stdio.h
stdlib.h
string.h
```

---

Even that is not the full story. In a subdirectory (avr) you will find the avr-related things, with files for different processors, such as (in part):

```
boot.h
builtins.h
common.h
cpufunc.h
crc16.h
delay.h
eeprom.h
fuse.h
interrupt.h
io1200.h
io2313.h
...
iox64d4.h
iox8e5.h
lock.h
parity.h
pgmspace.h
portpins.h
power.h
sfr_defs.h
signal.h
signature.h
sleep.h
version.h
wdt.h
xmega.h
```

---

As for the source of strcpy, I don't think it is in the distribution. They include the standard libraries, pre-compiled. For example, if you look in:

```
(install location)/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib
```

You will see various pre-compiled libraries, for example:

```
libc.a
libm.a
libprintf_flt.a
libprintf_min.a
libscanf_flt.a
libscanf_min.a
```

To find the source you would need to find where the AVR source of libc is (possibly at http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/).

---

As for the Mac, all this stuff is a few levels down in the "Application Package" which you can view by right-clicking and selecting "Show Package Contents". Look in the `Contents/Resources/Java` folder.

---

**None** of these places are where you should put your **own** libraries (ones you write or download). They should go into the `libraries` folder which is a subdirectory of your `sketchbook` folder. Create the `libraries` folder if it does not exist. That way user-installed libraries persist from one version of the IDE to the next.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may have changed in newer versions. On my Mac Big Sur, Arduino 1.8.15 they are here: `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries`