# Where can I find the source codes for the various classes and methods used in Arduino Primo?

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth

I am new to Arduino development. I am trying to connect a BLE device (Arduino Primo) with my iOS app. From the Arduino BLE examples, I understand how to initialize the BLEperipheral class and then call the setValue method to pass value to be transmitted. However I do not want to be dependent on example codes, rather I want read the source code and definitions to know about the available classes and their methods, what argument types passed etc.(not precompiled libraries with .o extension).

For my current issue, I want to know what type of arguments does the `setValue` take in the BLEperipheral class. Can I pass an int value(4 bytes) or it has to be a char only? These questions can be answered by reading the source code of these inbuilt libraries.

Any direction would not only help me with the current project, it would also help to tackle and understand any projects in the future, where I might use inbuilt library calls.

I have searched the internet, however not much information is available for newcomers like me. 
Below is a similar question link but outdated and does not solve what I am looking for.

[How can I get the source files for Arduino libraries?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/860/how-can-i-get-the-source-files-for-arduino-libraries)

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: you have them on your computer in arduino15 folder

Comment: Sir, i have checked all the folders in my computer and even my neighbours computer too. hehe. There is no such folder called ardunio15 nor any reference to the information i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino Primo is supported by Arduino nRF52 boards package. The boards packages can contain libraries special for boards handled by the package. The BLE library for Arduino Primo is included in the board package.

The location of boards packages on Windows is in hidden folder AppData in user's home directory. On my Windows computer it is

```
C:\Users\andrassy\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\nrf52\1.0.2\libraries\BLE
```

On Linux the 'Arduino 1.5' folder is `.arduino15` in users home folder.